# velocities transformations between frames

Tags: transformation

In my system, I have two frames.
I want to convert my velocities(x,y,z,r,p,y) in frame 1 to be represented in frame 2.
Does multiply the linear component and the angular component with the rotation matrix is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. The rotation matrix of the coordinates system B relative to the coordinate system A or its inverse backwards, A relative to B.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, as long as it's just rotation. If you have any translation, the equation to convert is:

\begin{equation}
\xi^b_n = \begin{bmatrix}
{R_b^a}^T & {R_b^a}^T S(d_b^a)\\
0_{3\text{x}3} & {R_b^a}^T
\end{bmatrix} \xi^a_n
\end{equation}

Where S is the skew-symmetric:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -d_3 & d_2 \\
d_3 & 0 & -d_1 \\
-d_2 & d_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

And $R^a_b$ and $d^a_b$ are from the $A^a_b$ homogenous transformation matrix.

And also where $\xi$ is $\begin{bmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \\ v_z \\ \omega_1 \\ \omega_2 \\ \omega_3 \end{bmatrix}$